# EFCore, запрос последнего значения из одной таблицы по каждому внешнему ключу

Tags: c#, postgresql, оптимизация, entity-framework-core

Есть таблица PoolingValues:

```
id  objectid  timecode   value
1   1         230238423  18
2   2         485230529  17
3   3         904230428  14
4   3         234324231  250
5   1         546542622  444
6   2         732623211  123
7   3         908942102  1
```

Нужно через EntityFrameworkCore3.1 в рамках одного запроса получить последние значения для каждого objectid из таблицы PoolingValues. Последние записи по timecode, но можно и по uid, если что timecode индексирован.
Например в виде List, в котором будет следующее:

```
id  objectid  timecode   value
5   1         546542622  444
6   2         732623211  123
7   3         908942102  1
```

Если делаю через цикл, где сначала читаю все objectid, а потом внутри цикла запрашиваю последнее значение для каждого objectid - то это очень долго, т.к. objectid в базе десятки тысяч уникальных записей, и пока цикл по каждому вернёт - пройдут минуты, к тому-же таких таблиц может быть несколько, не только PoolingValues.

Хотел сделать так:

```
var ids = context.Objects.Select(s => s.id).ToList();
context.PoolingValues.GroupBy(g => g.objectid)... //дальше не понятно что делать
context.PoolingValues.Where(w => ids.Contains(w.objectid)).Distinct(d => d.objectid)... //тоже не известно
```

Comment: У меня наконец появилось время и я вернулся к этому вопросу. .... Что ж вы метку используемой СУБД не ставите? Я отладил код в своём ответе на Sql Server. А дамп от Postgres. Лишь в чате вы об этом упомянули...

Answer (score 3):

Положим у вас есть класс:

```
public class PoolingValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ObjectId { get; set; }

    public int TimeCode { get; set; }
    
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Если вы хотите сгруппировать по ObjectId и взять максимальный Value - то пишите так:

```
var result = db.GroupBy(x => x.ObjectId)
               .Select(x => new { ObjectId = x.Key, Value = x.Max(y => y.Value)} );
```

Для ваших данных:

```
var db = new List<PoolingValue>()
{
    new PoolingValue { Id = 1, ObjectId = 1, TimeCode = 230238423, Value = 18  },
    new PoolingValue { Id = 2, ObjectId = 2, TimeCode = 485230529  , Value = 17  },
    new PoolingValue { Id = 3, ObjectId = 3, TimeCode = 904230428  , Value = 14  },
    new PoolingValue { Id = 4, ObjectId = 3, TimeCode = 234324231  , Value = 250  },
    new PoolingValue { Id = 5, ObjectId = 1, TimeCode = 546542622  , Value = 444  },
    new PoolingValue { Id = 6, ObjectId = 2, TimeCode = 732623211  , Value = 123  },
    new PoolingValue { Id = 7, ObjectId = 5, TimeCode = 908942102  , Value = 1  },
};
```

Результат будет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того, чтобы понимать группировку - надо внимательно посмотреть, что будет её результатом. Вот что будет после вашего `.GroupBy()`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же вам нужна более сложная логика для расчёта Value, скажем нужно внутренние Grouping отсортировать по убыванию TimeCode и взять Value то будет так:

```
var result = db.GroupBy(x => x.ObjectId)
               .Select(x => new { ObjectId = x.Key, Value = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeCode).Select(y => y.Value).First()} );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну или вот так для красоты:

```
var result = db.GroupBy(x => x.ObjectId)
               .Select(x => new PoolingValue {
                   ObjectId = x.Key,
                   TimeCode = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeCode).Select(y => y.TimeCode).First(),
                   Value = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeCode).Select(y => y.Value).First()
               });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отдельно пара слов по чисто EF'ным моментам. Я создал новый объект, анонимный из двух полей, тут можно было создавать либо тот же PollingValue (остальные поля проставятся в ноль), либо так и оставить анонимный класс без модели, просто аккуратнее материализировать на клиент, т.к. будет переход из серверной логики, которая выполнится на сервере в клиентскую. Но возможно, вы это знаете? Вопрос в общем-то был не об этом.

Comment: В вопросе же нужно брать не просто максимальное значение Value, а последнее (основываясь на timecode), не?

Comment: Не только Value, ещё и timecode, и есть ещё много полей, которые я тут не указал, но для запроса они не имеют никакой роли, нужны последние записи полностью.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Перечитал вопрос ещё раз. Да, похоже вы правы - нужно чуть более сложный запрос. Не проблема, добавил в ответ, так даже лучше вышло: постепенно показано как развивается и усложняется логика выборки.

Comment: Моя ошибка, я написал нужны последние значения, а нужно последние записи, исправил.

Comment: Немного исправил предложенный ответ: var result = db.GroupBy(x => x.ObjectId).Select(x => new { ObjectId = x.Key, Value = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeCode).First() }).Select(s => s.Value); кажется работает, сейчас вне linqpad'а перепроверю.

Comment: Очень интересный момент согласно которому в LINQPad'е работает var result = db.GroupBy(x => x.ObjectId)
      .Select(x => new { ObjectId = x.Key, Value = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeCode).Select(y => y.Value).First() }); А на реальной БД в том-же LINQPad'е получаю ошибку InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (r.ObjectId), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: PoolingValue
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)

Comment: А на реал БД в том-же LINQPad'е получаю InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (r.ObjectId), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
EntityType: PoolingValue
ValueBufferExpression: 
(ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
IsNullable: False
)).OrderByDescending(y => y.timecode)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). ToList() - добавлять пробовал

Comment: Реальный EFCore не может транслировать LINQ выражение с последовательностью .GroupBy().Select(=>{ ,.OrderByDescending.First()}).ToList()

Comment: @AK это работает только в памяти, на реальном EFCore не работает.

Comment: Мммм... Ну можно конечно временно поставить `.AsEnumerable()` и прочитав данные (всю таблицу!) рассчитать её на клиенте, но это такое... Подумаю, как можно собрать из конструкций поддерживаемый EF Core, @Blackmeser укажите точную версию, чтобы понимать, что у вас поддерживается, т.к. в Core разных версий может оказаться разный уровень поддержки конструкций.

Comment: @AK EFCore 3.1.12, записей в таблице актуально >106млн, в перспективе десятки-сотни миллиардов, по timecode индекс есть, но можно извлекать тупо последние по id, активно гуглю, везде пишут что OrderByDescending внутри GroupBy тупо не работает.

Comment: Такое количество точно не стоит на клиенте группировать. Посмотрю, не обещаю, что скоро - это уже не в linqpad'е скетч, это надо проект готовить.

Comment: @Blackmeser такие мегатаблички надо на партишны бить по какому-нибудь явному признаку.

Comment: @aepot Я тоже когда-то так думал, но в последнее время видел и примеры, когда это влияет в негативную сторону, так что есть и плюсы и минусы, надо взвешивать. Вот [тут есть на русском перевод статьи](https://habr.com/en/company/otus/blog/544876/), а вообще у Брента есть много полезных материалов вокруг sp_Blitz.

Comment: @aepot в табличку валится телеметрия с огромной скоростью, в зависимости от настройки может быть любая СУБД, не думаю что оптимизации с партишнами везде применимы.

Comment: Для логов точно партишны на основе промежутков времени применимы. Зачем хранить 1000 лярдов записей 100-летней давности в одной таблице? Не находите это странным? А с партишнами можно просто грохать старые таблицы или забирать их в архив не трогая таблицу, в которую прямо сейчас идет запись. Ну просто как идея.

Answer (score 1):

Примечание: данный в этом ответе код протестирован на Sql Server. И он работает быстро.
Однако, позже выяснилось, что автор использует PostgreSql. Генерация sql в разных провайдерах осуществляется по-разному. Очевидно, провайдер Postgres выдаёт менее эффективный код.

---

По моему скромному мнению, EF Core - жуткий фреймворк. И если есть возможность, следует отказаться от него. Одна из причин: сильно отличающаяся работа с разными СУБД.

---

Попробуйте следующий запрос:

```
var result = context.PoolingValues
    .GroupBy(x => x.ObjectId)
    .Select(g => g.Max(x => x.TimeCode))
    .Select(x => context.PoolingValues.First(y => y.TimeCode == x))
    //.ToList()
    ;
```

Он вернёт нужные вам данные.
Предполагается, что все значения TimeCode уникальные.

При этом будет выполнен всего один запрос в БД, что хорошо.
Сгенерированный SQL-запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[ObjectId], [t0].[TimeCode], [t0].[Value]
FROM (
    SELECT MAX([p].[TimeCode]) AS [c]
    FROM [PoolingValues] AS [p]
    GROUP BY [p].[ObjectId]
) AS [t]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) [p0].[Id], [p0].[ObjectId], [p0].[TimeCode], [p0].[Value]
    FROM [PoolingValues] AS [p0]
    WHERE [p0].[TimeCode] = [t].[c]
) AS [t0]
```

---

Иногда запрос очень сложно выразить с помощью LINQ, но легко написать на обычном SQL. К счастью, EF позволяет выполнять сырые запросы SQL.

```
string sql =
@"select *
from PoolingValues
where TimeCode in
(
    select max(TimeCode)
    from PoolingValues
    group by ObjectId
)";

var result = context.PoolingValues
    .FromSqlRaw(sql)
    //.ToList()
    ;
```

---

Написав сырой запрос, я понял, как можно выразить его в LINQ.

```
var result = context.PoolingValues
    .Where(x => context
        .PoolingValues
        .GroupBy(y => y.ObjectId)
        .Select(g => g.Max(x => x.TimeCode))
        .Contains(x.TimeCode))
    //.ToList()
    ;
```

Сгенерированный SQL:

```
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[ObjectId], [p].[TimeCode], [p].[Value]
FROM [PoolingValues] AS [p]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [PoolingValues] AS [p0]
    GROUP BY [p0].[ObjectId]
    HAVING MAX([p0].[TimeCode]) = [p].[TimeCode])
```

Прошу потестить все три варианта на реальных данных.

---

P.S. EF Core не так уж плох. :) Но только для Sql Server.

Comment: TimeCode значения не уникальные. Нужно взять не максимальные, а последние, среди миллиардов записей .Max() очень долго отрабатывается и у меня вылетает по таймауту. Но на GroupBy уже не ругается.

Comment: Точнее они должны быть уникальными, но их уникальность никто не гарантирует. Т.к. в программе предусмотрены попытки перезаписи в случае ошибки (та же ошибка таймаута), и если будут дубли - это не проблема, проблема - это если данных вообще нет. А от дублей можно избавиться кастомным Distinct'ом.

Comment: @Blackmeser - `.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeCode).First()` - равноценно `.Max(x => x.TimeCode)`. Если вас устраивает первое, то годится и второе.

Comment: @Blackmeser - _.Max() очень долго отрабатывается_ - но вы же писали,  что timecode индексирован. Это должна быть мгновенная операция. / В общем, информации недостаточно. Я зря потратил время, к сожалению.

Comment: `.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ObjectId))` - нужно добавить в мои варианты запросов. Позже сделаю.

Comment: Именно так, он индексирован, перепроверил (https://i114.fastpic.ru/big/2021/0505/18/07d0a5306781cf1c8ce64adebdce3418.png), в БД с 106.000.000 записей в PoolingValues оба запроса возвращают ошибку: Timeout during reading attempt

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123808/discussion-between-blackmeser-and-alexander-petrov).

Comment: Последний "Сгенерированный SQL" выполняется до сих пор XD, уже 4й день =)